# Slow GridView Resize in UWP

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-10, win-universal-app

To simplify the example let's suppose we just add a GridView in the Page:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="MainGrid" />
</Grid>
```

And this is the code:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        MainGrid.ItemsSource = collection;

        await Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(test =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            {
                collection.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        });

    }
```

A GridView is filled with that ObservableCollection, I do not complain about scrolling but about resizing and maximizing the Window makes a huge lag and even worse in low spec computers.

I have done the following improvements:

1. Play with the values of IncrementalLoadingThreshold & DataFetchSize

```xml
<GridView x:Name="MainGrid" IncrementalLoadingThreshold="100" DataFetchSize="3"/>
```

Sometimes goes better but not sure if this values works with an static collection.

2. Change the alignment to top and left to track the SizeChanged and adapt to the Grid.

This goes better but when I tap on maximize it has a large lag.

I have also tried to follow old examples like  http://xurxodeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/scroll-infinito-en-windows-81-con-xaml.html but it does not add more items when scroll has arrived to the end. And the performance tips and articles I found are just for scrolling.

So In this static case, is there a technique or another collection source to improve the resizing lag?

Comment: Two side notes: there is no need to run on dispatcher the last line - after returning from `await Task...` it's already running on captured UI context. Second - don't modify ObservableCollection (used with UI control) in *non-UI* thread - you will get exception - your case works because the collection is being set as itemssource of the UI element after it has been filled, if you exchange the order, it won't work. But as I've mentioned those are side notes not connected with your question.

Comment: Well I began to cut code from testings, I have updated the code, I think is cleaner now, thanks for the aside, Any idea about another collection that could work better?

Comment: ObservableCollection seems to be a good one - it's desingned to work with UI elements in such cases. I don't know how to make it work better, I would try to search something with *GridView's* (*ListView's*) *IncrementalLoading* - don't load all items when not needed - maybe try to search something about ListView and incremental lading, methods *LoadMoreItemsAsync* and so on. Though I'm not sure how this will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a new Observable Collection that allows you to AddRange. Here's what I have

```
public class ObservableCollection2<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    bool _suppressNotification = false;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

        // do nothing
    }

    public ObservableCollection2() : base() { }
    public ObservableCollection2(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    { }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        this._suppressNotification = true;

        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        int index = this.Count;

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            base.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this._suppressNotification = false;

        OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items[]"));
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, list.ToList(), index));
    }
}
```

Next you don't instantiate the collection on Loaded rather do it in constructor

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        dataCol = new ObservableCollection2<String>();
    }

    ObservableCollection2<String> dataCol = null;

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    MainGrid.ItemsSource = dataCol;

    List<stirng> tempList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    {
        tempList .Add(i.ToString());
    }
    dataCol.AddRange(tempList);

}
```

In short you aren't triggering UI updates after every insert only when the collection has finished processing.. that means GridView gets update notification once rather than 2000 times

Comment: Might be I have not explained well, the issue I want to solve is after any time you resize the window, the control takes a lot of time into refresh itself. The loading is not the issue. Thx anyway

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about the lag in GridView Layout.. you could look at 3rd Party Controls like Telerik.. I have started using RadDataBoundListBox as stock controls do not offer a specific feature